# GetType() and passing on parameters and an objectname

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way to call a method from a class and passing on some parameters with getType() by passing on the objectname of the class?

```
    public void ForeachInsert(object tblnaam, string error)
    {
        tblnaam.GetType().GetMethod("nameOfMethod");
//where to place string error?
    }
```

Comment: Looks a lot like C#, I edited the tags ...

Comment: What is your question here? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

```
MethodInfo mi = tblnaam.GetType().GetMethod("nameOfMethod");
object myResukt = mi.Invoke(tbknaal,your_parameters);
```

Invoke method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx

Comment: +1, and when mi should be null, he has to use BindingFlags (for private members, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is - this is all part of Reflection. Once you have the MethodDescriptor you can use it to execut ethe method on a specific class instance and turn int parameters.

Check the content of your tblnaam - it is not "object" but should be a MethodInfo actually.